# versionNameSuffix for product flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

Is there any way to set different `versionNameSuffix` for various product flavors in a way it is possible to do this for build types?

The following code works for me:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            verstionNameSuffix "-prod"
        }
}
```

But when I want to set `versionNameSuffix` for product flavors like this:

```
productFlavors {
        production {
            versionNameSuffix "-prod"
        }
        development {
            versionNameSuffix "-dev"
        }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error:(48, 0) Could not find method versionNameSuffix() for arguments [-dev] on ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=development, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=null, targetSdkVersion=null, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=null, versionName=null, applicationId=null, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={BASE_URL=com.android.builder.internal.ClassFieldImpl@1630a8db}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.
```

Is there any other way to set the `versionNameSuffix` for the product flavor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing so. Currently, `com.android.application` gradle-plugin does not support any DSL for `productFlavors` to have `versionNameSuffix`.

If you want to do this, you have to create two methods.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import java.util.regex.Pattern

def getCurrentVersionSuffix() {
    def currentFlavor = getCurrentFlavor()
    if (currentFlavor.equals("prod")) {
        return "-prod"
    } else if (currentFlavor.equals("uat")) {
        return "-uat"
    } else if (currentFlavor.equals("dev")) {
        return "-dev"
    }
}

def getCurrentFlavor() {
    String taskRequestName = getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()

    Pattern pattern;

    if (taskRequestName.contains("assemble"))
        pattern = Pattern.compile("assemble(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")
    else
        pattern = Pattern.compile("generate(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(taskRequestName)

    if (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.group(1).toLowerCase()
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

and update the `buildTypes` DSL

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        versionNameSuffix getCurrentVersionSuffix()
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        versionNameSuffix getCurrentVersionSuffix()
    }
}
```

This is the only way to achieve right now. May be in future, they could provide some DSL or something.

I have written a blog on this (http://www.pcsalt.com/android/product-flavors-android/) and the code is pushed on GitHub (https://github.com/krrishnaaaa/product-flavours/blob/master/app/build.gradle).

Answer (score 2):

productFlavors now support versionNameSuffix

From the android developer docs

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#flavor-dimensions

```
android {
  ...
  buildTypes {
    debug {...}
    release {...}
  }

  // Specifies the flavor dimensions you want to use. The order in which you
  // list each dimension determines its priority, from highest to lowest,
  // when Gradle merges variant sources and configurations. You must assign
  // each product flavor you configure to one of the flavor dimensions.
  flavorDimensions "api", "mode"

  productFlavors {
    demo {
      // Assigns this product flavor to the "mode" flavor dimension.
      dimension "mode"
      ...
    }

    full {
      dimension "mode"
      ...
    }

    // Configurations in the "api" product flavors override those in "mode"
    // flavors and the defaultConfig block. Gradle determines the priority
    // between flavor dimensions based on the order in which they appear next
    // to the flavorDimensions property above--the first dimension has a higher
    // priority than the second, and so on.
    minApi24 {
      dimension "api"
      minSdkVersion 24
      // To ensure the target device receives the version of the app with
      // the highest compatible API level, assign version codes in increasing
      // value with API level. To learn more about assigning version codes to
      // support app updates and uploading to Google Play, read Multiple APK Support
      versionCode 30000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
      versionNameSuffix "-minApi24"
      ...
    }

    minApi23 {
      dimension "api"
      minSdkVersion 23
      versionCode 20000  + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
      versionNameSuffix "-minApi23"
      ...
    }

    minApi21 {
      dimension "api"
      minSdkVersion 21
      versionCode 10000  + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
      versionNameSuffix "-minApi21"
      ...
    }
  }
}
...
```

You can also operate on productFlavors like this:

```
android.productFlavors.all { flavor ->

    flavor.versionNameSuffix = "-${flavor.name}"

}
```